# MVC 4 website is using deleted/cached controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, controller, edit

I'm developing a MVC 4 website on IIS7.5 and have run across a strange issue that I cannot find a solution for. When I edit or delete a controller, the website doesn't recognize the change and seems to be using a stored version somewhere. I have disabled output cache and kernel cache on the server and added measures to prevent client side cacheing to no avail. This is a really bizarre problem that I haven't been able to find a solution for anywhere.  Editing or deleting the controller affects my local machine but not the server!

Comment: I'm assuming you're deleting the dll that the controller is compiled in off the server?  Perhaps too the previous developer loaded the assembly into the GAC.

Comment: I forgot about the project .dll on the server. After uploading the newly compiled .dll, everything works fine. Thank you.